# If statement for line colours

Tags: javascript, if-statement, colors, highcharts

Please can you assist..
I am currently making a chart which will have two lines within it, a total needed line(black) and a total collected line(red or green). I would like to add an if statement to the code which will identify whether the line will be green or red.  It should be green when it is above the total needed black line and red when it falls below.  In my code I have made provision for what it may look like given the scenario.

```
    $(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Total Contribution'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
    },
    labels: {
        items: [{
            html: 'Student VS Total contribution',
            style: {
                left: '-10px',
                top: '0px',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'black'
            }
        }]
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'John',
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b>: R{point.y:.0f}'
        },
        data: [3000, 2000, 1000, 3000, 4000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 7000, 9000, 6000, 9000]
    },

    {
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Total Needed',
        lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b>: R{point.y:.0f}'
        },
        data: [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000, 11000, 12000],
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
            fillColor: 'white'
        }

    }, {
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Total Collected - Good example',
        lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[6],
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b>: R{point.y:.0f}'
        },
        data: [3000, 5000, 7000, 7000, 9000, 10500, 11000, 12000, 12000, 13000, 14000, 14000],
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[6],
            fillColor: 'white'
        }
    }, {
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Total Collected - BAD example', // The data in the columns does not match - it is an example
        lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[8],
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b>: R{point.y:.0f}'
        },
        data: [1000, 1000, 2000, 2000, 3000, 3000, 4500, 4500, 6000, 7000, 7000, 8000],
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[8],
            fillColor: 'white'
        }
    },

    {
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Contribution',
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.2f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.0f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        data: [{
            name: 'John',
            y: 25,
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0] // John's color
        }, {
            name: 'Total',
            y: 75,
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[7] // Other's color
        }],
        center: [30, 45],
        size: 100,
        showInLegend: false,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false,
            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.0f} %'
        }
    }]
});
  });
```

Also see here:
http://jsfiddle.net/warricksmith/ae4wajw2/

Comment: It depends - do you mean that you want the entire line red/green in each case, or will you want the line to change color as it goes above/below the required value?  If you want it to change, it becomes more difficult and you need to look at multiple series, and decide what part of the line to actually change color on for a data point below the threshold.  If the red line will always be red, just pre-process your data and set the color before hand.

Comment: The chart will be used as a budgetting tool... I think as long as the overall data of one of the lines is in a state above or below the total needed line, it should reflect one colour?

Comment: You'll need to determine how you are going to define 'overall data' being above or below.  Once you've done that, do your calculations on the data sets first, and define the color as a variable that you can then invoke in the chart code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, if you want to use the average values of each series to compare, you could this:

1) define your data for each series in an array

2) calculate the average of your 'required' series.

3) compare the average of each other series to that average, defining the color for each series accordingly

along the lines of:

```
var requiredAvg = getAvg(requiredData);
var requiredColor = 'black';
var goodColor = getAvg(goodData) > requiredAvg ? 'blue' : 'red';
```

example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/te2zxo88/

Comment: Thanks alot, this is definitely down the right track